# Show Access Report in dialog

Tags: c#, ms-access, interop

I want to show a Access Report without showing the MainForm from Access. I want to show it in a Dialog or something like that. I can show a report but with opening the Main Window of Access:

```
        _access.DoCmd.OpenReport(
            "myReport", //ReportName
            AcView.acViewReport, //View
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            "my Where Condition"
        );
```

But this opens Access all the time. I only want to see my Report in a Dialog. Even when I set the `AcWindowMode.acDialog` property it opens Access behind it.

I also know that I can save it as PDF and open this. But this is not possible in my case.

Is there a way to show a Access Report in a Dialog without showing (or hiding) the Access Main Window behind it?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: @June7 Okay, thank you for your answer. So I have to search a other solution for that.

Comment: if you choose tabbed UI in Access, then only the report and report ribbon should show. And you can even hide the ribbon if you want. Just setup Access to use tabbed interface, and set the option to hide tabs. At that point you only see report + ribbon. This has to be a accDB for this to work, not a mdb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

First, in the access application, set the interface to tabbed. and un-check show tabs.

Now write a code stub in a standard code module in Access.

Say like this:

```
Sub RunMyReport(s As String)

  DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
  
  ' now launch report
  
  DoCmd.OpenReport "qryHotels", acViewReport

End Sub
```

Now, your .net code will look like this
(I not even bothering with interop - it don't help much).
You have this .net code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim objAccess As Object = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("C:\test\test44.accdb")

    objAccess.Run("RunMyReport", "qryHotels")
    objAccess.Visible = True

End Sub
```

And the results will now look like this:

```
note the vb form that launched the form.

Note the Access report, 
it shows no ribbon or background interface.
```

[image]

And note that we get to pass the report name to the given routine.
Now you likely could move the VBA code of this:

```
 DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
  
  ' now launch report
  DoCmd.OpenReport "qryHotels", acViewReport
```

To the .net side, and not even have to call a VBA routine.

```
    Dim objAccess As Object = CreateObject("Access.Application")

    objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("C:\test\test44.accdb")

    objAccess.DoCmd.ShowToolbar("Ribbon", 2)       ' acToolbarNo = 2
    objAccess.DoCmd.OpenReport("qryHotels", 5)     ' acViewReport = 5

    objAccess.Visible = True
```

So, in fact we don't need the VBA helper function, and we can open any report. The command to hide the ribbon works, and the other settings (hide nav pane, and tabbed interface is to be set in the access application).

So above should work. Given it only a few lines of vb.net code, then as c#, it should be easy to convert. Eg this should work:

```
{
var objAccess = Interaction.CreateObject("Access.Application");
objAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"C:\test\test44.accdb");
objAccess.DoCmd.ShowToolbar("Ribbon", 2);       // acToolbarNo = 2
objAccess.DoCmd.OpenReport("qryHotels", 5);     // acViewReport = 5
objAccess.Visible = true;
}
```

You can consider the inter-op assemblies, as that can help in intel-sense, but above is written without any references to office or use of the inter-op assemblies.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It looks very clean and exactly what I want.